# User input displayed at wrong coordinates in OpenCV

Tags: visual-c++, opencv

I'm trying to display circles at a user accepted input (usually centers), using OpenCV 2.4.3 (VS 2010). On output image (displayed using 'namedWindow') circle seems to shift column-wise as one marks points along columns. Not sure how I should correct this.

**Code:**

```
struct OPTIONS{
        OPTIONS(): X(-1), Y(-1), drawing_dot(false){}
        int X;
        int Y;
        bool drawing_dot;
    };
    OPTIONS options;
    void my_mouse_callback( int event, int x, int y, int flags, void* param ){

        IplImage* image = (IplImage*) param;

        switch( event ){

        case CV_EVENT_LBUTTONDOWN:
            options.X = x;
            options.Y = y;
            options.drawing_dot = true;
            break;
        default:
            break;
        }
    }
    int main( void ){
        IplImage* image = cvLoadImage("Images/TestRealData/img1.bmp");
        Mat frame = imread("Images/TestRealData/img1.bmp");
        namedWindow("Test", CV_WINDOW_KEEPRATIO);
        cvSetMouseCallback("Test", my_mouse_callback, (void*) image);
        while( cvWaitKey(15) != 27 ){
            if( options.drawing_dot ){
                circle(frame, Point(options.X,options.Y), 3, CV_RGB(0,0,255), 2);
                options.drawing_dot = false;
            }
            imshow("Test", frame);
            waitKey(10);
        }
        cvReleaseImage(&image);
        return 0;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found answer after much time lost - 
Make sure to specify flags in 'namedWindow'. Changing flag to CV_WINDOW_KEEPRATIO did the trick for me. Hope this helps somebody out there.

Answer (score 2):

I think the circle does not shift. The mouse cursor may trick our eyes. You may simply check it by increasing the radius and reduce the thickness of the circle outline like:

```
circle(frame, Point(options.X, options.Y/2), 15, CV_RGB(0, 0, 255), 1);
```

By the way, I think if you want to draw the circle at the point you click on, `options.Y` should not be divided by 2.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to look through the code. Yes, the 'options.Y/2' was indeed a bug, but I forgot to update the change here. Have done so now. Also, found where I was going wrong - I hadn't mentioned any flags for 'namedWindow'. Changing that did the trick. Thanks again!